# How to import Redis rdb file to Heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, migration

I need to import Redis data from a private server to a Heroku Application. The problem is that the server is not accessible from outside, and the only way to import the data to Heroku app is via `data.rdb`.
Some Heroku addons, like "Heroku Redis", "Redis Enterprise Cloud" and others offer migration solution, but only by forking the data from another server/Redis, which has to be accessible from the outside.

TLDR; Is there a way to import Redis data from a rdb file on my machine to my Heroku app?

Answer (score 1):

To anybody having the same issue: I previously used "Heroku Redis" addon, which does not have an easy data import solution. At the time of writing this, they offer only importing data from another Redis Server (which I did not have).

How I solved this was to use another Redis addon called [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud) which offers more data import solutions, one of them being importing via Amazon S3. So, I've just created an S3 bucket there (for free), uploaded my redis dump.rdb in that bucket, and imported it via said redis addon dashboard. The whole importing process is documented nicely in the redis enterprise cloud docs link.